# Conditional error of rock, paper and scissors

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a rock, paper and scissors by Javascript. The program works, however, the output is wrong. For example, if I define the userInput ComputerInput, I want the output is Tie. However, sometimes returns an incorrect answer. May I know why does it occurs? Herewith the code:

```
function getUserChoice(userInput) {
  if (userInput === "rock" || userInput === "paper" || userInput === "scissors") {
    return userInput
  } else {
    console.log("Input Error")
  }
}

let userInput = 'ROCK'
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

userChoice = getUserChoice(userInput)
console.log(getUserChoice(userInput))

function getComputerChoice () {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      return "rock"
      break;
    case 1:
      return "paper"
      break;
    case 2:
      return "scissors"
      break;
  }
}

computerChoice = getComputerChoice()

console.log(getComputerChoice())

if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
  console.log("Tie!")
} else {
  console.log("Try again!")
}
```

Comment: `getComputerChoice()` is called twice, so depending on the Random result it may console.log a different result than what is used in the comparison.

Comment: console log computerChoice instead of getComputerChoice()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
computerChoice = getComputerChoice()

console.log(getComputerChoice())
```

you are calling getComputerChoice() 2 times, and printed value and computerChoice value can be different, because function return random values.

for testing just print value of the computerChoice instead of new function call

console.log(computerChoice)

Answer (score 2):

You have to log the variable
`console.log(computerChoice)`

instead of the function itself
`console.log(getComputerChoice())`

since getComputerChoice() is a function which generates a random number and in this case is being called twice which will generate a different number than what is being used in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly "tighter" version of your script, following the DRY principle:

```js
const choices=["rock","paper","scissors"];
let userInput = 'ROCK'
userChoice = getUserChoice(userInput);
if (userChoice>-1) {
 console.log("user: "+choices[userChoice]);
 computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
 console.log("computer: "+choices[computerChoice]);
 console.log(userChoice === computerChoice
             ?"tie"
             : userChoice===(computerChoice+1)%3 
               ? "you win ": "you loose " )
} 
else console.log ("wrong user input.")

function getUserChoice(userInput) {return choices.indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase());}
function getComputerChoice () {return ~~(Math.random()*3);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you call getComputerChoice() twice, the result they return is probably different.
So you must log the computerChoice variable.
If you don't, the program might be working , but you won't realise it